# Changing Facebook page names after 200 likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

*The last discussion I can find about this topic is from 2011, thus a new thread.*

Officially Facebook page names cannot be changed after 200 likes and group names cannot be changed after 250. In other places I read that if you just got over 200 likes changing the "type" to a group might be an option.

However, my "author page" has 1000+ likes so that doesn't work for me. I can't find any way around it. I would be able to verify the new name with the name on my ID.

On the Facebook help pages several threads about "changing page names" exist (e.g. [this one.](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200812615545565)), but so far it seems no FB employee reacted to them.

Is there any known trick/method/strategy/... to change a Facebook page's name after 1000+ likes?
Or just any method (pay for ads? Email Mark Zuckerberg?) that worked for you?

Comment: Haha, messaging mark zuckerberg will cost you $100. I don't think it's possible to change the name. But some people have weird ideas of making it possible, they deactive the page, and then reactive it after a few days and they are able to change name then. I have never tried this.

Comment: Thank you. Would be fascinating to hear if someone had success with that - and if so I'd likely give it a try.